# How to configure HTTPS services/api on kong

Tags: microservices, api-gateway, kong, konga

Previously I configured api/services on **Kong** as **HTTP** and it was working fine. Now I made api/services as **HTTPS** in back end and I changed protocol **http** to **https** for all api/services on **Kong**. But after changing **http** to **https** protocol i unable to access api's.

Can you please tell me what I have to do?
Here is my services configuration on kong
[image]

Route
[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS is used to protect data exchanges from anyone looking into them.

You are configuring data exchange between your gateway and upstream servers.

Your microservices are most likely deployed into the same closed virtual private network where kong gateway is located.

It is unlikely that anyone could sniff on data traffic which goes between API gateway and your microservices.

Setup of encryption in your virtual private network will just waste computational resources which you could allocate to extra workers which do usefull things.

What you probably need is to configure SSL certificate at kong gateway public interface.
To do this you can add your SSL certificate in Konga GUI in CERTIFICATES section.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. You means enabling certificate is mandatory for https api's calls?

Comment: @AnilJagtap Sure. you need to use proper certificate for your clients to use your api in a secure way. Nowadays everyone is concerned about privacy so it makes sense to not give your clients any concerns. You can start with LetsEncrypt for free ( https://discuss.konghq.com/t/how-to-use-letsencrypt-for-kong/354/2 ) and later decide whether you need another certificate which provides extra verification of identity.

Comment: without enabling certificate can I access https api?

Comment: @AnilJagtap, Try and see. If you can connect and see no  warnings then you are already set. If you see warnings but still could connect with warnings disabled (like curl --insecure **) then you need to setup proper certificate because your clients will not trust such connection. You can use SO chat or contact me via skype(see my profile) to continue further questions.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Neither it's correct. No HTTPS within a private network means anyone who ever gets inside your network can spoof any traffic and completely take over your network. Zero trust architectures where even internal services communicate over https over authenticated connections is the new standard.